# Is there a superposition of two density matrices?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, superposition, density-operator

Say I have two density matrices $\rho_0 = \sum_{i,j} \alpha_{i,j} |i\rangle \langle j|$ and $\rho_1 = \sum_{i,j} \beta_{i,j} |i\rangle \langle j|$. What is the density matrix $\rho$ corresponding to the equal superposition of the two?

In particular (re-framing the question), say there is some CP map $S$ that maps the pure state $|0\rangle \langle 0|$ to $\rho_0$ and maps the pure state $|1\rangle \langle 1|$ to $\rho_1$. Then what is the effect of $S$ on $\frac{1}{2} \cdot (|0\rangle+|1\rangle) \cdot (\langle 0|+\langle 1|)$?

Comment: Your normalization is off, unless psi_1 and psi_2 are orthogonal.  --  What do you mean by "express directly"?  You have expressed it in terms of rho_0 and rho_1 -- you need to find their non-zero eigenvectors and work your way from there.

Comment: The example I gave seemed not to be helpful, so I rewrote the question.

Comment: Well, now it is not clear at all what you mean by "superposition".  There is no such notion for density matrices.  Unless they represent pure state, which brings us back to the original version.

Comment: I guess that is my question. =) I'll try to add further clarification...

Comment: The answer is "there is no such thing".  You can *mix* density matrices.

Comment: I'm not sure if the clarification I added helps at all.

Comment: "Sequence S of unitary transformations plus measurements": Does this mean CP maps? Or just projective measurements, where you select for one outcome? (In the latter case, rho_0 and rho_1 are still pure states.  In the former case, no-one can tell what the effect of S on |0>+|1> is.)

Comment: *"I'm not sure if the clarification I added helps at all."* -- We overlapped, but you better spell out what S is (write formulas!).

Comment: I meant CP maps, but it sounds like the answer in that case is that  "no one can tell what the effect of S" is. Thanks!

Comment: Suggestion: You edit the question to clarify that S is a general CP (or CPTP) map. Then the question can be reopened. And then I can explain *why* no-one can tell what the effect of S is.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to reopen the question even after I edited it.

Comment: @user6584 Once a question has been closed, the community must vote to reopen it (I have done so).

Comment: @user6584 Thanks for the edit. You can also ping Qmechanic to open it (I think the question is clear now).

Comment: The part about $\vert 0\rangle + \vert 1\rangle$ makes no sense.  If the $\rho$’s are mixed states that are not expressible as kets (which describe pure states).

Comment: @ZeroTheHero As it is now, the 2nd part makes complete sense (if you interpret all states as density operators).

Comment: @user6584 Following the discussion with StevenSagona: What is your real question: The first paragraph or the second? In particular, I don't understand the phrase *"re-framing the question"* in the second paragraph: The first paragraph simply makes no sense, the second asks a well-defined and answerable question.

Answer (score 3):

In the setting you describe, you cannot say much about the effect on the state on $\lvert+\rangle\langle+|$ (with $|+\rangle=(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$.

To see why, consider the two channels (acting on qubits)
$$
S_1(\rho) = \tfrac12(\rho+Z\rho Z)\ ,
$$
which sets the off-diagonal entries to zero, and $S_2(\rho)=\rho$ (the identity channel).

Then,
\begin{align}
S_1(|0\rangle\langle0|)&=S_2(|0\rangle\langle0|)=|0\rangle\langle0|\ ,\\
S_1(|1\rangle\langle1|)&=S_2(|1\rangle\langle1|)=|1\rangle\langle1|\ ,
\end{align}
that is, $S_1$ and $S_2$ act identically on $|0\rangle\langle0|$ and $|1\rangle\langle1|$.

On the other hand, $S_1(|+\rangle\langle+|)=\tfrac12 I$, while $S_2(|+\rangle\langle+|)=|+\rangle\langle+|$, so $S_1$ and $S_2$ have vastly different effects on $|+\rangle\langle+|$.

Thus, knowing how a channel acts on $|0\rangle\langle 0|$ and $|1\rangle\langle 1|$ does not allow you to conclude how it acts on $|+\rangle\langle+|$.

(As a side note, this is not that surprising, since the space of $2\times 2$ matrices (to restrict to qubits) is four-dimensional, so you need to know the effect on at least 4 different states to uniquely fix the channel.)

Note that you can e.g. also consider $S_1'(\rho)=\tfrac12(\rho+X\rho X)$ and $S_2'(\rho)=\tfrac12 I$:  They map both $|0\rangle\langle0|$ and $|1\rangle\langle1$ to the *same* output $\tfrac12 I$, so one might be tempted to think that $S'_\bullet$ is constant, yet, they have very different effects on $|+\rangle\langle+|$.

---

It is an interesting question how much we *can* actually say about $S(|+\rangle\langle+|)$ given $S(|k\rangle\langle k|)$ $k=0,1$.  For sure, we can use that CPTP maps (or generally trace-nonincreasing CP maps) are contractive w.r.t. the trace norm, and thus, $\|S(|+\rangle\langle+|)-S(|k\rangle\langle k|)\|_1\le \sqrt{2}$, which gives some non-trivial constraint (but as we saw from the example above, not enough to fix $S(|+\rangle\langle+|)$, even if $\|S(|0\rangle\langle0|)-S(|1\rangle\langle1|)\|_1$ is maximal. Yet, there might some some other non-trivial things to say - but that is probably another question.

Answer (score -1):

I asked a similar question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/277509/can-density-matrices-be-coherently-added-without-having-to-go-back-to-the-schrod).

**You can generate superpositions of density matrices, but this is only super clear when everything is a pure state.** This is a sort of trivial case, because the purpose of the density matrix is to work with mixed states, so if you're states are always pure it is usually pointless to try to generate the superposition of two mixed states.

My old question that I asked tried to work out the math for this, to figure out how to create superpositions in the density matrix picture without having to convert the pure state density matricies back to bras and kets and then convert back. I still don't know how to do this for general cases. So while it may be practically pointless to create superpositions in the density matrix framework when working exclusively with pure states, it's not so easy (to me) to work out the math for doing this in the general case.

**But I am pretty sure that you are also able to create superpositions of mixed states.**

A superposition of mixed states is a bit unusual conceptually, because a mixed state is created specifically to deal with states that are not in quantum superpositions - so I think there will be some that might insist such a thing doesn't exist, but I think you can do this.

Consider the following thought experiment, which I'm going to call Schrodinger's coin flip:
I put my friend in a black box, and inside the box is a quantum coin, a regular coin, and a weighted coin.  The "quantum coin" is in a superposition of heads and tails $|\psi\rangle = |H\rangle + |T\rangle$, the normal coin is a normal coin and would have to be represented as a density matrix: $\begin{bmatrix}
    1/2       & 0 \\
    0      & 1/2 
\end{bmatrix}$,  and the weighted coin is some kind of coin used for cheating and has a 90% chance of being heads, and therefore has a density matrix of the form:
$\begin{bmatrix}
    9/10       & 0 \\
    0      & 1/10 
\end{bmatrix}$.

So here's what I'm going to do. I'm going to ask my friend to make a measurement of the quantum coin, and he is going to flip the normal coin if he measures $|H\rangle$, and flip the weighted coin if he measures tails $|T\rangle$.

**Then in my perspective, he must be in a superposition of these two possibilities. But these two possibilities are mixed states! And therefore we have created a superposition of mixed states.**

The state that I observe will have the form:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|F_H\rangle \otimes \rho_{NC} + |F_T\rangle \otimes\rho_{WC})$$

which is a superposition of two mixed states. (I should mention that writing an outer product of a density matrix and a pure state is very unconventional, but I am not sure that this can be written in a more conventional form since superpositions of mixed states aren't normally considered.) This is basically a copy of the [Wigner's Friend thought experiment](https://www.google.com/search?q=wigner%27s%20friend&rlz=1C1ZKTG_enUS818US818&oq=wigner%27s%20fri&aqs=chrome.0.0i457j69i57j0l6.3870j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) but where the friend flips classical coins when measuring a quantum state.

EDIT:
Norbert criticizes that writing the above state is meaningless unless I've established a way of evaluating it, which is a good point. (Personally, I think it is conceptually obvious that this is a superposition of a mixed state and that developing a whole formalism to evaluate these states is overkill to answer that question, but I think its interesting nonetheless.)

if we considered two general coins with distributions:

$$\rho_{wc} = \begin{bmatrix}
    p      & 0 \\
    0      & 1-p 
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\rho_{nc} = \begin{bmatrix}
    q      & 0 \\
    0      & 1-q 
\end{bmatrix}$$

So in our case, our mixed states are just classical probabilities, so we can work out each superposition as being generated from the combinatoric possibilities:

$$
\begin{align*}
 p q\%: & \quad  \frac{1}{2} \Big(|H_{nc}\rangle  \otimes |F_{H,nc}\rangle  + |H_{wc}\rangle   \otimes |F_{H,wc}\rangle \Big)   \\
 p (1-q)\%: & \quad  \frac{1}{2} \Big(|H_{nc}\rangle \otimes |F_{H,nc}\rangle  + |T_{wc}\rangle  \otimes |F_{H,wc}\rangle\Big) \\ 
 (1-p) q \%: & \quad  \frac{1}{2} \Big(|T_{nc}\rangle \otimes |F_{T,nc}\rangle + |H_{wc}\rangle  \otimes |F_{H,wc}\rangle \Big) \\
 (1-p) (1-q)\%: & \quad   \frac{1}{2} \Big(|T_{nc}\rangle \otimes |F_{T,nc}\rangle + |T_{wc}\rangle \otimes |F_{T,wc}\rangle\Big) 
\end{align*}
$$

So here we end up with a statistical mixture of multiple entangled states. If we want to keep track of the probabilities of each outcome, we can get these termms by collecting the elements in $\rho_{wc}\otimes \rho_{nc}$

And if the normal coin and the weighted coin are the same coin (and maybe I'm just changing how I flip it), then this can be reduced to:

$$
\begin{align*}
 p q\%: & \quad|H\rangle  \otimes |F_{H}\rangle  \\
 p (1-q)\%: & \quad \frac{1}{2} \Big(|H\rangle \otimes |F_{H}\rangle  + |T\rangle  \otimes |F_{H}\rangle\Big) \\ 
 (1-p) q \%: & \quad \frac{1}{2} \Big(|T\rangle \otimes |F_{T}\rangle + |H\rangle  \otimes |F_{H}\rangle\Big) \\
 (1-p) (1-q)\%: & \quad  |T\rangle \otimes |F_{T}\rangle 
\end{align*}
$$

Overall, we see that there are meaningful ways of calculating and working with the state generated by the thought experiment. While it's true that such a state can be eventually reduced to a large density matrix, I think it's reasonable to conceptually think of this as a superposition of two statistical mixtures.

Comment: The last equation (expresssion) makes no sense as a state.

Comment: If you do what you suggest properly, then e.g. the coin should be produced by producing a state $\sqrt{p}|00\rangle+\sqrt{1-p}|11\rangle$, depending on the quantum control state, and then tracing the second part.  This will leave you with a mixed state, yet with some coherences between the two mixed sectors.  Indeed, this would give some "combination" of mixed states. Yet, this is different from the question since your "combined" mixed state has an additional system which wasn't there in the beginning.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, your response isn't clear. I give an example involving three coins (two mixed, and one quantum) and you include two entangled qubits which with one parameter p. It's not clear how any of this is connected to what I'm talking about.
Also, obviously doing an outer product of a mixed state and a density matrix is unconventional, but I think it's a reasonable construction to characterize such an effect.

Comment: Finally, I believe the essence of the question was if it is possible to create superpositions of mixed states, and I specifically wrote this question because I saw in the comments that you said that density matrices can only be mixed, which I think is misleading.  So I gave one example of the trivial case where this is true (when things are pure), and one unconventional example to try to demonstrate that there can be superpositions of two separate mixed states.

Comment: *"doing an outer product of a mixed state and a density matrix is unconventional"* -- I guess you mean "outer product of pure state and density matrix"?  Mathematically, this is of course completely clean, but what it means in the context of quantum theory is completely unclear. E.g., if you were to measure an observable on this "thing", how would you compute the expectation value, or the probability for a certain outcome?  (Also, it is not clear at all what this "thing" has to do with the experiment you describe.)

Comment: ... by the way, I commented on an earlier version of the question that one can of course take the vectors corresponding to the two pure state and take the density matrix describing their superposition. But this is apparently not what the OP asked.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, I don't understand the second part of the question - but since the title still remains as "Is there a superposition of two density matrices?" - I still think it's reasonable to provide an answer to that part for other users who might be reading it.

Comment: Certainly, the rule you just added only seems to apply for *diagonal* density matrices.  This is a very, very, very special case.   What if the density matrix describes a quantum system and I want to perform a joint measurement? Or do you restrict to classical states/systems? Then the real question would be "are there superpositions of classical states", the answer to which is "yes" (but not what you give).

Comment: And, *"I don't understand the second part of the question"* -- that's the only one which is well phrased and asks a clearly defined question.  To be honest, I was thinking of removing the first part before flagging for re-opening.

Comment: While it is clear that I have not developed a complete formalism for creating a superposition of all possible mixed states - that's a bit of a tall order, considering that it seems as though it's a unique idea and would take some work to get to be perfect (maybe worthy as a small paper? idk). Also, I think it's a completely well-posed question to ask if superpositions of mixed states can be constructed since we both agree it is obvious they can be for pure states.

Comment: Ok, just to be clear: You do *not* claim that this is a new theory outside of quantum mechanics, but that this is a theory *within* quantum mechanics, right? (Otherwise, well, ...).  Then, of course we can make superpositions of pure states. One way to extent it to mixed states would be via purifications. But then it would not be unique, as it would depend on the choice of the purification. The same is true for other definitions. One could try to make those unique (e.g. by insisting on purifications with minimal or maximal distance, in case those are unique), and if done well (min. distance?)

Comment: ... it *might* collapse to superposition for the case of pure density matrices. But this doesn't change the fact that this is *not* a superposition of density matrices. A meaningful question would maybe be "how can the concept of "superposition" be extended to non-pure density matrices". I acknowledge that this is a valid question (feel free to ask it!), but your construction, involving some entirely unphysical objects, seems far from it, unless you use very contrived constructions for measurement. (Differently speaking, *any* measurement in quantum theory can be modeled by a density matrix...

Comment: ... so if it fits within quantum theory, you *must* be able to write a density matrix (rather than a product of pure state vectors and density  matrices) describing the very same state.